# Regarding changing the 32 bit OS to 64 bit OS

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

My desktop PC is running a 32-bit OS. How can I change it to a 64-bit OS? To do this, do I have to change the processor, too?

Comment: i need to full systems information in your Desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can only run a 64 bit OS on a processor supporting 64 bit. So if your current processor doesn't you have to change it.

To go from a 32 bit OS to a 64 bit OS you'll have to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what OS you want. Linux, Windows?

If you want Windows 10 64-bit for example you would need to have at least 2 GB of RAM 20GB Disk Space, and a processor that supports 64 bit instruction set. If you Google the name of your processor you can probably find a page with information that tells you if it has this or not.

Otherwise let me know and I'll Google it for you.

Comment: `cmpxchg16b` this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this Microsoft FAQ.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15056/windows-7-32-64-bit-faq)

> The terms 32-bit and 64-bit refer to the way a computer's processor (also called a CPU), handles information. The 64-bit version of Windows handles large amounts of random access memory (RAM) more effectively than a 32-bit system.

If I remember correctly, I believe the limitations are, you need at least 2GB of RAM to run a 64-bit OS. 32-bit Operating System can only use up to 4GB of RAM, because that's the max amount of storage for memory addresses.

Comment: I *strongly* discourage running 64-bit systems on 2GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

To change your current 32-bit OS installation to a 64-bit OS, you need to perform a fresh install, which means you'll (probably) lose all your data stored in the system volume, and you have to re-install most, if not all, softwares.

As you didn't say which OS you're running, which can differ *a lot* in system requirements. To run a 64-bit Windows system (assume it's not Windows XP 64-bit), you need at least 2 GB RAM and 20 GB hard drive. This is the *minimum* requirement. From my experience, 4 GB RAM + 64 GB hard drive is *recommended*. If you're going to change to 64-bit Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, your CPU must support the `CMPXCHG16b` instruction, which is a common feature supported by all Intel Core 2 or later, or AMD Phenom 64 processors, so if your computer was bought or assembled in the last 10 years, CPU is not something to worry about.

If you're going to run a 64-bit Linux like Ubuntu or Fedora, the requirement is much lower. You can cut the RAM requirement by half, and older CPUs are supported. But don't expect a new OS will run fluently on *ancient* hardware. It's still recommended that you have 4 GB RAM and 32 GB hard drive for a 64-bit Linux installation.

If it's a Mac, give it up :)